# problem with HttpContext in mvc 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, session, web-applications

i get an error when i try to access HttpContext.Current from a controller.
I want to get the session to add some session specific data, and this gives me a problem:

var a = HttpContext.Current.Session;

The error, allegedly is that 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i try to access HttpContext.Current from a controller

You should never use `HttpContext.Current`.

Simply use the [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.session.aspx) property to access the session:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Session["foo"] = "bar";
    ...
}
```

The reason for the error you are getting is because the controller class already has a property called [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext.aspx) so when you write `HttpContext.Current` it is the property that is used and not the static `Current` property on the `HttpContext` class.

Comment: thanks! this solved it. on the other hand, how can you neatly retrieve the session object from a class you program and import? i don't have the Session object outside the controllers i think.

Comment: @Bruno Figares, you should never use session outside of the ASP.NET MVC standard classes that have access to the session (controllers, action filters, helpers, ...). So your custom classes don't fetch data from session. It's bad practice. You pass them this data from the controllers, ...